# React - setState in function gets executed X times - Updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Quick Overview:
I have a context with **meals** in it. That **meals** gets used in the *MealDetails-Component*. In this component is a list filled with a certain amount of *Food-Components*. If you click on the X in the Food component it gets removed otherwise you go to the FoodDetailsPage

Then when I press the button a function called *deleteFood* gets executed which sets the **meals** state new without that food. The problem is that the setState inside the function doesn't get called once but twice in this component. I tried using it in 2 other components and once it executed only once and in the other it executed 4 times.

**Update**

My addFood function has a pretty similiar problem. But this one gets called in another component. It adds Food to 2 different states in 2 different contexts and in both contexts the added Value is doubled. One thing I could "find" was that the console in my browser prints the a certain value I console logged inside the setState function a second time, but not via the MealsContext, but via **react_devtools_backend.js**.
And this only happens with those 2 functions where I have an error.

**Update 2**

I'm displaying the Food-Components inside the MealsDetails Component which has **meals** in it which comes from the MealsContext. Could this be the problem?

**Update 3**

I missed saying it. I have a lot more functions in this MealsContext that are changing the state. One of them is called changeFoodWeight and it gets called in the same component where addFood gets called, but it doesn't show any problems plus the **react_devtools_backend.js** logs nothing which is great. I added the function to the MealsContext down below.

MealsDetails.tsx

```
const MealDetails = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  let { id } = useParams();
  const { meals } = useMeals();

  const style = { "--percentage": "75%" } as React.CSSProperties;

  return (
    <div className="MealDetails">
      <header className="BarcodeScannerHeader">
        <ArrowBackIcon
          onClick={() => {
            navigate("/");
          }}
          sx={{ fontSize: 35 }}
        ></ArrowBackIcon>
        <div className="HeaderText">{meals.meals[Number(id)].name}</div>
      </header>
      <div className="MealDetailsContent">
              <span className="label">{meals.meals[Number(id)].calories} ate</span>
        <hr className="SolidMealDetails"></hr>
        {meals.meals[Number(id)] != null
          ? meals.meals[Number(id)].food.map((food: any, index: number) => <Food key={index} food={food}/>)
          : "Not loading"}
      </div>
      <Link className="Link" to={`/AddFood/${id!}`}>
        <div className="MealDetailsAddFoodButton">
          <img className="SVG" id="SVG" src={SVG} alt="+" />
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

MealsContext.tsx

```
let initialState: MealsType = {
  calories: 0,
  carbs: 0,
  meals: [
    {
      calories: 0,
      carbs: 0,
      food: []
    }
  ],
};

const MealsProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [meals, setMeals] = useState<MealsType>(initialState);

const addFood = async (
    id: number,
    addedFood: FoodType,
    selectedLocation: string,
    date: Date
  ) => {
      //Removed the fetch for readability
      console.log("func")
      setMeals((prevMeals) => {
        console.log("state");
        const updatedMeals = prevMeals;
        let foodExists = false;

        updatedMeals.calories += addedFood.kcal;
        updatedMeals.carbs += addedFood.carbs;
  
        updatedMeals.meals[id].calories += addedFood.kcal;
        updatedMeals.meals[id].carbs += addedFood.carbs;
  
        updatedMeals.meals[id].food.forEach((food : FoodType) => {
          if(food.code === addedFood.code){
            food.kcal += addedFood.kcal;
            food.carbs += addedFood.carbs;
            foodExists = true;
          }
        })

        if(!foodExists){
          updatedMeals.meals[id].food.push(addedFood);
        }
  
        return {...prevMeals,updatedMeals};
      });

      setUser(prevUser => {
        const updatedStorage = prevUser.storage;
  
        updatedStorage.map((storage : any) => {
          if(storage.location === selectedLocation){
            storage.storedFood.map((storedFood : any) => {
              if(storedFood.code === addedFood.code){
                storedFood.weight -= addedFood.weight;
              }
            })
          }
        })
  
        return {...prevUser, updatedStorage};
      })  
  };

const changeFoodWeight = async (
    id: number,
    foodDiff: any,
    selectedLocation: string,
    date: Date,
    newWeight: number
  ) => {
      //Removed the fetch for readability
      console.log("func");
      setMeals((prevMeals) => {
        console.log("state");
        const updatedMeals = prevMeals;
        updatedMeals.calories += foodDiff.kcalDiff;
        updatedMeals.carbs += foodDiff.carbsDiff;
  
        updatedMeals.meals[id].calories += foodDiff.kcalDiff;
        updatedMeals.meals[id].carbs += foodDiff.carbsDiff;

  
        updatedMeals.meals[id].food.forEach((food) => {
          if (food.code === foodDiff.code) {
            food.kcal += foodDiff.kcalDiff;
            food.carbs += foodDiff.carbsDiff;
          }
        });
  
        return {...prevMeals,updatedMeals};
      });

      setUser(prevUser => {
        const updatedStorage = prevUser.storage;
  
        updatedStorage.map((storage : any) => {
          if(storage.location === selectedLocation){
            storage.storedFood.map((storedFood : any) => {
              if(storedFood.code === foodDiff.code){
                storedFood.weight -= foodDiff.weightDiff;
              }
            })
          }
        })
  
        return {...prevUser, updatedStorage};
      })
  };

const deleteFood = (id: number, deletedFood: FoodType) => {
    setMeals((prevMeals) => {

      const updatedMeals = prevMeals;

      updatedMeals.calories -= deletedFood.kcal;
      updatedMeals.carbs -= deletedFood.carbs;

      updatedMeals.meals[id].calories -= deletedFood.kcal;
      updatedMeals.meals[id].carbs -= deletedFood.carbs;

      for(let i = 0; i < updatedMeals.meals[id].food.length; i++){
        if(updatedMeals.meals[id].food[i].code === deletedFood.code){
          updatedMeals.meals[id].food.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }

      return {...prevMeals,updatedMeals};
    });
  };
 return (
    <MealsContext.Provider
      value={{
        meals,
        deleteFood
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MealsContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useMeals = () => useContext(MealsContext);

export { MealsProvider, useMeals };
};
```

Food.tsx

```
const Food = ({ food }: any) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const {deleteFood} = useMeals();  

  return (
    <Link className="FoodContent Link" to={`/FoodDetails/`}  state= {{ food: food , location: location.pathname}} >
      <div className="Food">
        <div className="FoodDetail">
          <div className="FoodNameFoodDelete">
            <div className="FoodName">{food.name}</div>
            <img className="FoodDelete SVG" onClick={(e : any) => {e.preventDefault(); deleteFood(parseInt(location.pathname[location.pathname.length - 1]), food)}} src={SVG}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="FoodGram-FoodKcal">
            <div className="FoodBrand-FoodGram">
              <div className="FoodBrand">{food.brand + ","}&nbsp;</div>
              <div className="FoodGram">
                {food.weight ? food.weight + " g" : 100 + " g"}{" "}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="FoodKcal">{food.kcal} kcal</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="FoodNutritions">
          <div className="FoodNutrition">
            <div className="FoodNutritionGrams">{Math.round(food.carbs*10)/10} g</div>
            <div className="FoodNutritionText">Carbs</div>
          </div>
          <div className="FoodNutrition">
            <div className="FoodNutritionGrams">{Math.round(food.protein*10)/10} g</div>
            <div className="FoodNutritionText">Protein</div>
          </div>
          <div className="FoodNutrition">
            <div className="FoodNutritionGrams">{Math.round(food.fat*10)/10} g</div>
            <div className="FoodNutritionText">Fat</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Comment: `updatedMeals` is a direct reference to `prevMeals` so in essence you're directly modifying state.

Comment: @RubenSmn isnt this the way to do things like that? I thought its normal.

Comment: It would be better to do: `const updatedMeals = { ...prevMeals };` so it's actually a brand new object. Edit* Then at the bottom of that function, simply `return updatedMeals;`

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu I tried this approach, but it didn't work sadly.

Comment: There's a lot of issues with state mutations in your code.  But to answer the question at hand: wrap `deleteFood` etc. in `useCallback` so that the function variable is the same across re-renders.  Otherwise you have a new function each time.  You could possibly use `useMemo` for the state value itself so that the object doesn't get re-recreated.  However the context will still change when the `meals` state changes.  You can possibly have separate contexts for providing the `deleteFood` handler, which doesn't change, and the `meals` value which changes frequently.

Comment: I'm reading this again and realizing that the the actual problem you are having is that functions are getting called multiple times?  That's not an issue of re-renders.  Minimizing re-renders is really just a performance thing whereas you have an actual bug.  I could be of more help if you can provide some fake data https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-germain-f56rxv?file=/src/App.tsx But you definitely need to get your state mutations sorted.  No it is not normal.  You need to be careful about this sort of deep mutation as well: `updatedMeals.meals[id].calories +=` even if you create a new array.

Comment: Sry for answering so late. The problem is not that the function gets called twice, but the setState inside the function. I dont understand why every other method in this context that changes state works, but deleteFood and addFood doesnt.

Comment: Linda I had some problems with codesandbox... so I decided to push the project to Github. https://github.com/cinc-b/GainsAndNutritions/tree/main/gains-and-nutrition-ts
I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe not a solution, but a couple of remarks/pointers: initialState.meals.push(newMeal); - I don't think it should be done like this since the initial state is (*should be) read only once, thus this may cause issues. secondly don't put console.log inside the setMeals (or any 'setState' function) since both are (can be considered as) 'async'. Also be aware that hot-reload can cause some calls/re-renders that might look like more calls are happening then expected. See if deployed (production version) behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from *wrapping your entire component* with a `Link` tag which is causing some internal state-collision between your `setMeals` call and the `Link` state pass.

```
<Link className="FoodContent Link" to={`/FoodDetails`}  state= {{ food: food , location: location.pathname}}>
   <div>Block-level Elements...</div>
</Link>
```

`Link` is an `inline` element and is simply meant to wrap some text (or a word) that's to be used as a link somewhere. The resulting view can then access the passed-in state.

From the [React Router Link v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#state) documentation on how to handle passing `state`:

> The state property can be used to set a stateful value for the new location which is stored inside history state. This value can subsequently be accessed via useLocation().

`<Link to="new-path" state={{ some: "value" }} />`

> You can access this state value while on the "new-path" route:

`let { state } = useLocation();`

In your situation, the Link wrap is trying to passing the `food` state object into the entire `Food` component as you are updating your entire context state (`useMeals`).

To better visualize the problem, I reproduced your issue ["before"](https://fnvpk8-3000.preview.csb.app/) and ["after"](https://skrs3i-3000.preview.csb.app).

In the "before" sandbox, clicking `Delete Cookies` removes more items than anticipated due to this issue. In the "after" sandbox the same steps work as expected. This is because only the actual link is wrapped in `Link`.

Essentially, you need to use your `Link` wrap more like this so the `state` it's trying to pass doesn't overwrite the state that's in the component:

```
const Food = ({ food }: any) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const {deleteFood} = useMeals();  

  return (
    <div className="FoodContent">
      <div className="Food">
        <div className="FoodDetail">
          <div className="FoodNameFoodDelete">
            <Link className="FoodName Link" to={`/FoodDetails/`}  state= {{ food: food , location: location.pathname}} >{food.name}</Link> {/* <--- Just wrap the actual link */}
            <img className="FoodDelete SVG" onClick={(e : any) => {e.preventDefault(); deleteFood(parseInt(location.pathname[location.pathname.length - 1]), food)}} src={SVG}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="FoodGram-FoodKcal">
            <div className="FoodBrand-FoodGram">
              <div className="FoodBrand">{food.brand + ","}&nbsp;</div>
              <div className="FoodGram">
                {food.weight ? food.weight + " g" : 100 + " g"}{" "}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="FoodKcal">{food.kcal} kcal</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="FoodNutritions">
          <div className="FoodNutrition">
            <div className="FoodNutritionGrams">{Math.round(food.carbs*10)/10} g</div>
            <div className="FoodNutritionText">Carbs</div>
          </div>
          <div className="FoodNutrition">
            <div className="FoodNutritionGrams">{Math.round(food.protein*10)/10} g</div>
            <div className="FoodNutritionText">Protein</div>
          </div>
          <div className="FoodNutrition">
            <div className="FoodNutritionGrams">{Math.round(food.fat*10)/10} g</div>
            <div className="FoodNutritionText">Fat</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here are the sandboxes for reference:

["Before" Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/great-cartwright-fnvpk8)

["After" Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/weathered-shape-skrs3i)

Comment: This didnt work for me.

Comment: I tested your sandbox. And the "dirty" way logs 2 (one real console and one via react_devtools_backend.js) times like my deleteFood and the other one logs 4 times (2 real consoles and two via react_devtools_backend.js). If you cant see the other logs you could (if you want) install the reactdevtool extension. This console.logs in a greyed out way the second one.

Comment: Based on your explanation I was expecting you to break it up into two contexts: one for the `meals` state and the other for the update functions.  This is an approach that is sometimes used to reduce re-renders in components which need to access the updaters but not the state itself.

Comment: You're absolutely right Linda. @Cinc-B I found the problem. Revising my answer.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu Ty for reworking your answer, but it still doesn't work. The food component is not the only problem the MealDetails component has wrong values in it too.

Comment: That's odd - the sandboxes work perfectly for me in reproducing your problem and fixing it. Sounds like you have a lot more code going on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to check out return values after calling setState?
Your setState function seems completely wrong. You have to return like this:

```
return {...prevMeals, ...updatedMeals};
```

Anyway you are getting reference of previous state in updateMeals and having something with them so it will look be working.